# What is the best place to pull data from query string, then call API and render components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, state

I'm trying to pull data from query string, then call API and render components and filters right, but state works asynchronously and I can't do it like:

```
state = {
  currentPage: 1,
  sort: {
    name: '',
    salary: '',
  },
};

componentDidMount() {
  this.handlePullSortFromQuery();
  this.handlePullPageFromQuery();
  this.handleUploadData();
}
```

Instead I tried use `this.handlePullSortFromQuery()` and `this.handlePullPageFromQuery()` in `constructor()`:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    currentPage: 1,
    sort: {
      name: '',
      salary: '',
    },
  };

  this.handlePullSortFromQuery();
  this.handlePullPageFromQuery();
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.handleUploadData();
}
```

But my state don't update at all and I get this warning:

**Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application. Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};` class property with the desired state in the _temp component.**

So how it works? How I can solve the problem? And in what place I should pull query string data?

Comment: Can you also share the contents of the functions `handlePullSortFromQuery`, `handlePullPageFromQuery` and `handleUploadData` so we can see what you're trying to do there?

Comment: it seems like you are using `setState` in `this.handlePullSortFromQuery()` and `this.handlePullPageFromQuery()`. It is generally considered best to make api calls after the component is mounted i.e. in `componentDidMount` and to show loading while the results load.

Comment: Yes, i'm using `setState` in handler functions, but I think, that if I initialize state before calling functions this will work

Comment: If I use it in `componentDidMount` the state can't updated and stay as previous before API call, so i decided to pull date from query string in constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed state works asynchronously, but putting your functions calling setState inside your constructor is not the solution anyway.

You could either make use of async/await or calling your functions in callbacks in order to execute them in order.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    await this.handlePullSortFromQuery();
    await this.handlePullPageFromQuery();
    await this.handleUploadData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue I simply call functions in constructor, return value instead of `setState` and then initialize state as result of function calls.

```
constructor(props: any) {
  super(props);
  const { page, sort } = parseQueryString(props.location.search);
  const currentPage = this.handlePullPageFromQuery(page);
  const sortQueryObject = this.handlePullSortFromQuery(sort);

  this.state = {
    currentPage,
    sort: sortQueryObject,
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.handleUploadData();
}
```